# Difference between agg() and aggregate() function in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

So, I was going through agg() and aggregate() in pandas. And found both to give similar output.
Here is the code which gives similar output for both the functions. So, just wanted to understand wat is the difference between both of them.

```
data = {'Name': ['Giggs', 'Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Jack', 'Jill', 'Scholes', 'Martial', 'Rashford', 'Pogba'],
        'Age': [23,21,24,21,20,10,23,45,22,35],
        'Rating': [4.23, 3.21, 2.10, 1.91, 4.32, 6.32, 4.19, 2.09, 1.09, 3.33],
        'Teams': ['Man Utd',"PSG",'Real Madrid','Real Madrid', 'Man Utd', 'Man City','Man City','PSG','Man Utd','PSG'],
        'Year': [2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2016, 2014]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


print(grouped.agg('Rating').sum())
print("------Aggregation function---")
print(grouped.aggregate('Rating').sum())
```

Comment: according to [this doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), `agg` is an alias for `aggregate`, i.e. they do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 14):

The [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) says

> `agg` is an alias for `aggregate`. Use the alias.

It is the same.

Comment: Same, but less typing ;) so lazy coder use `agg` ;)

Comment: This should be an accepted answer I reckon ...